# Theorem numbering style: How to make number appear before name?

Tags: theorems

I am currently writing an essay for a class in Functional analysis I'm taking. Now in one of the theorems I have it appears as :

> [image]

How can I make it so that the number one comes before `(Peter-Weyl)`? Ideally, I would like the thing to appear as:

> **Theorem 1 (Peter-Weyl).**

How can I do this? In my preamble at the moment I have:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{peterweyl}{Theorem (Peter-Weyl) }
```

Comment: Please indicate whether you load the `amsthm` or the `ntheorem` package (or if you do neither).

Comment: I have ``amsthm``.

Comment: One usually does not do it that way but rather has a `thm` env that points to wards a `Theorem` header and then one writes `\begin{thm}[Peter-Weyl]`, then one can have both named and unnamed theorems and the number is adter the heading.

Comment: @daleif Code to do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
```

in the text

```
\begin{thm}[Peter-Weyl] Blah blah
\end{thm}
```

The `[thm]` on the proposition is to make them share the number.